# Build proper sum formula in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out how excel can fill down a column if i make a function like sum(A1:A2), sum(A1:A3) and so on. i have had no luck thus far with successfully filling as what would occur is the following result for the respective cells; sum(A1:A2), sum(A2:A3). I am sure there is a very simple fix but I am not typically an excel user.

Comment: try `=sum(A$1:A2)`

Comment: thanks,do you know if the syntax be like this (AA$1:A2) for multi letter columns?   Edit: that worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: It works, but it ain't the 'proper' way to do it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be tempting to enter the simple formula `=SUM(A$2:A2)` into B2 and copy it down, if you're going to sum large ranges this is actually *incredibly* inefficient on large ranges compared to the formula `=SUM(B1,A2)`

Why? Let's say you copy `=SUM(A$2:A2)` down 10 rows.

- Your result at row 2 only had to sum **1** number: the number in A2.
- Your result at row 3 has to sum **2** numbers: the numbers in A2:A3.
- Your result at row 4 has to sum **3** numbers: the numbers in A2:A4.
- ...
- Your result at row 11 has to sum **10** numbers: the numbers in A2:A11.

So how many numbers did Excel have to add in total to produce the answers you calculated in B2:B11?
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55

But if we're using the other approach i.e. `=SUM(B1,A2)`  then all we're doing for each row is adding the number to the left to the previously calculated sum above. So on each row, we sum only two numbers together. Meaning to produce the same 10 answers, the amount of numbers that Excel has to add to produce the exact same totals in B2:B11 are:

2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2 = 20

Now let's extrapolate that, to some sizeable ranges.

[image]

Yikes! So how much does this matter in the real world, given we've all got pretty fast computers good at math?

If you fill rows A2:A100000 with some numbers and then put `=SUM(B1,A2)` in B2 and fill down, it takes well under a second to calculate on my PC. But if you put `=SUM(A$2:A2)` instead, it takes almost a minute.

My advice: Get out of the habit of using `=SUM(A$2:A2)`. One day you'll thank me for it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight! I can imagine that this method is very useful and saves much time and stress on a computer when dealing with enormous data sets. I will be sure to keep this in mind in future.

Comment: Cool. Note that I'm going to amend my answer...I used a more complex formula than you need. All you need is SUM(B1,A2) copied down, which does the same thing. Don't know why I went with the N version (although it works fine). Even better, use a PivotTable to do this...they spit out Cumulative Sums with no formulas at all. I'll add that to the answer too, for the next person who comes here via Google.